# OleDB newLine character

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oledb, oledbcommand

I have problem with oleDB \n \r parsing.

I want to pass multi-line string to database. Query looks line this:

```
"{call merge_procedure(12345, 'Datum poskytnutí '||chr(13)||chr(10)||' dokumentace')}"
```

- chr(13) => \r
- chr(10) => \n

but command execution fails on

```
Unspecified error
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.InitializeCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean throwifnotsupported)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

## What I've tried:

- 'Datum poskytnutí \r\n dokumentace'
- 'Datum poskytnutí ' + Enviroment.NewLine + ' dokumentace'
- Changing single quotes to double

Could you please help me, how to pass multi-line string to database using oleDB?

Comment: Did you try prepared statements with bind parameters?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit
 Yes! You are a GOD, thank you so much :) It works when i do 

`string.Format("call merge_procedure(12345, 'Datum poskytnutí {0} dokumentace'))", Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: Usually I would put the entire argument as parameter variable., i.e. `"call merge_procedure(12345, {0})"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit) wrote in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637975/oledb-newline-character/64765935#comment110771272_62637975), if I bond parameters it works.

`call merge_procedure(12345, {0})`

or in C#

`string.Format("call merge_procedure(12345, 'Datum poskytnutí {0} dokumentace'))", Environment.NewLine);`

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting the string like (if it is in c#):

@"Datum poskytnutí
dokumentace"